# Does low reputation cause the user to have any restrictions?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What are the restriction given by a low reputation?

Do the modalities of giving answers or interact with other Stack Exchange users would change ?

Comment: No, reputation is capped at 1 for the lower bound.

Comment: @Glorfindel there was additional question here, I edited to focus on it so it's not a dupe.

Comment: I bet that question has been asked before as well...

Comment: @Glorfindel not in such a way, pretty sure of that. If you find something let me know though. :)

Comment: See the [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) for what rep gives you.

Comment: @gnat This was closed as a dupe of that, but later reopened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) and of [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the prior close was right, the later reopening was wrong (you should have simply edited two posts listed in your comment into dupe list instead)

Comment: @gnat no, the faq doesn't say anything about restrictions.

Comment: this is a problem of the faq @ShadowWizard - references to canonicals about restrictions should be edited in it somehow

Answer (score 4):

> What are the restriction given by a low reputation?

No direct restrictions are placed *due to the low reputation*, but it goes the other way around: you start with minimal set of things you can do (e.g. Ask, Answer, etc) and you *gain privileges* as you get reputation points.

This is explained in detail in the faqs here on Meta: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) and more.